# How to dynamically resize the UI Grid according to the number of records?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

firstly I dont want vertical scroll bar 
I'm doing something like this

`var height = (rowLength*30)+100;`
`angular.element(document.getElementById('grid1')).css('height', height + 'px');`

with this I am able to resize the grid but it always shows the number of records visible to the viewspan.
For ex. I have 40 records fetched from the rest side and resized the grid accordingly but it would only display 25 records and remaining page goes blank.

Any share on this one?
Thanks!

Comment: for future reference http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/api/ui.grid.autoResize (this is beta at the time of writing)

Answer (score 3):

You can use their `auto-resize` directive, as shown in [their tutorial page](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/api/ui.grid.autoResize.directive:uiGridAutoResize).

Another easy way is to use style-attribute with auto-resize

```
<div id="grid2"
  ui-grid="vm.gridOptions"
  ui-grid-auto-resize
  style="height: {{vm.desiredTableHeight + 'px'}}; width: {{vm.desiredTableWidth + 'px'}};">
</div>
```

When `vm.desiredTableHeight` or `vm.desiredTableWidth` change, angular will notice and the directive will trigger.

Comment: It comes with a warning: This works by adding a checker on 250ms interval that sees if the grid element has changed in size. It could potentially affect the performance of your site or application negatively.

Comment: I'm not sure this directive is even hooked up correctly to determine an elements width or height. Looks partially implemented at best.  `elementWidth` isn't even defined https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/1536f6187d9ce2d0be496169aa763b7c3dbac8d9/packages/core/src/js/services/ui-grid-util.js#L442

It certainly doesn't look to be checking the actual size of the element in question.

Comment: `gridApi.core.handleWindowResize()` works.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer to my question was the property `virtualizationthreshold` to be set to number of rows, by default it is around 20 and hence the rows appeared blanked since the grid never rendereed completely

Answer (score 0):

`ui-grid-auto-resize` seems rather poor and incomplete.

You can instead force a re-calculation of col sizes and queue a refresh with:

`gridApi.core.handleWindowResize();`